# do not show error if file doesn't exist on copy, without sending to dev null

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I want to avoid my script posting an error if I try to cp a file that does not exist.  However, I would like error messages to print out for any other error, such as insufficient permissions.  This means I can't send the messages to dev/null.  what other solutions are there to do this in a script?

One option is an if statement to check if the file exists before copying, but it seems rather cluttered approach.  I think I can get what I want by adding an * in the file's name, though it seems an odd way of doing things.  is there some command line argument or other way to get what I want?

Comment: "an if statement to check if the file exists before copying" is a reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check **IF** the directory/file already exists:

- to copy a *file*

  `file=path/to/the/file/to/copy && [ -f "${file}" ] && cp ${file} destination/path/here`
- to copy a *directory*

  `dir=path/to/the/dir/to/copy && [ -d "${dir}" ] && cp -r ${dir} destination/path/here`

**NOTE:**

the spaces **before/after** the square brackets are mandatory, not to break the above commands.

*REFERENCES:* https://linuxize.com/post/bash-check-if-file-exists/

Answer (score 2):

You might do like:

```
{ command <doesntexist cp doesntexist 2>&3 ; } 3>&2 2>/dev/null
```

It might be shorter in a subshell...

```
( <file cp file ... 2>&3 ) 3>&2 2>/dev/null
```

But it still seems like a long way around doing...

```
[ -r file ] && cp file ...
```

All of those only test for readable files though - they won't work for directories...

But...

```
[ -e file ] && cp file ...
```

...could...

Answer (score 2):

Checking for existence will reduce the problem, but in the most general case it's a race condition.  The file could still be removed between the check and the copy attempt.

Perhaps just capture all errors and drop any for "file doesn't exist".

Normal copy:

```
$ cp noexist bar /tmp
cp: cannot stat `noexist': No such file or directory
cp: cannot open `bar' for reading: Permission denied
```

Modified

```
$ cp noexist bar /tmp 2>&1 | grep -v "No such file or directory" >&2
cp: cannot open `bar' for reading: Permission denied
```